# Japanese text not working in Java

Tags: java

I have application in which I stored Japanese text in one of column in DB.It saved successfully.

When I do search for Japanese  text using Firefox I am able to search the records.

But Japanese  text search is not working for **IE9 and Chrome**. In my jsp I have set UTF8 encoding as,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

any suggestion why it is not working for IE9 and Chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q1: What text is being sent by the browser for the search process? Q2: How is the text being searched for in the database? Are you using Hibernate or Oracle query? Q3: If you trace the submitted search text, how does it differ between FF, Chrome & IE?

Comment: 1.I am searching text like さよなら. 2.I am getting text from jsp page in java side as ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(req, "mytext");3.I am using hibernate query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and test in chrome:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

and it needs to be the first meta tag in HEAD

Comment: @user1835444 It has to be the first meta tag in head. Hope you have it that ways

Comment: .Yes i have that way only but no luk .<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "mojibake" problem. Check what character encoding is being used to store the text, as well as the character encoding that is being used in Java, and the character encoding that is being declared to the client.

- They need to all match.
- They need to be supported by all the devices that will be used to access your site/service.

The best choice for modern browsers is UTF-8. In the past SHIFT_JIS was a commonly used encoding, however I believe just about all browsers will happily work with UTF-8 now.

UTF-8 will contain just about every character in every language, whereas other encodings like SHIFT_JIS contain a subset. . . There are many character encodings that won't support any Japanese characters at all.